# jenkins : Error fetching remote repo 'origin' : Could not resolve proxy

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am getting the following error while launching a build in Jenkins:

```
unable to access 'https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git/': Could not resolve proxy: ncproxy1
```

I tried to set a proxy on http.proxy and https.proxy git variables but it deosn't fix the issue.

Please find below output console on Jenkins :

```
Démarré par l'utilisateur Driss EL BOUKILI EL HASSANI
10:45:41 Connecting to https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/api/v3 using git/******
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 87f7009f727ab2f7945d90866ece908eff2b1f14
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on LeanFT-UFT in C:\SlaveJenkins\workspace\admtest_BDD_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Preparation)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential abb1c2f8-44fb-4840-8611-1528095698f8
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching without tags
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
Setting http proxy: ncproxy1:8080
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://gitscm-    mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:894)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1148)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1179)
    at         org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120    )
    at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCM    Step.java:90)
    at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master"     returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git/': Could not resolve proxy: ncproxy1

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from bdss00900275.xbd.net.intra/10.78.242.148:55405
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor748.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:892)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1148)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

**FI: The "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://gitscm-mikasa-irb.rb.echonet/irb/BDD_CREDIT_CONSO.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" command is a success when performed from the slave jenkins node.**

Thank you.